# How to get top users of quarter using query in data.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, data-explorer

I want to query top users by reputation in quarter of specific location in `data.stackexchange.com`.

Result like 
https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter  but I want to add location filter also. I try to find any similar query for top user by reputation for a year/quarter/month something like that but couldn't find any.

To specific:
A user list

- Order by reputation
- Specific time range start date and end date
- Top 3 tags in the specified time range
- Filter by location and location details in result
- User Link in result

Comment: I have [this query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268067/158100) but that needs an update as it still uses the 5 rep per question upvote logic.

Comment: another alternative from me: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268008/158100 with the same issue but without location

Comment: @rene Thanks. You can update it since it's outdated

Comment: Can you let me know if one of those queries is close to what you need because then I'm happy to add the bits to make it a good fit on your question and provide it as an answer.

Comment: @rene Both are close but I want to merged results. I actually want like the similar result as `https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter`  I updated question.